# How come .filter can find a tag while .find can't?

Tags: jquery

Try these two lines in Chrome Console (with jQuery context of course):

```
$('<head><title>FooBar</title></head>').find('title')
```

will yield `[]`, but

```
$('<head><title>FooBar</title></head>').filter('title')
```

gives `[<title>​FooBar​</title>​]`. But in this example, `<title>` *is* the descendant of `<head>`, so shouldn't it be found using `find`?

Can someone explain why not?

Comment: I would assume that elements in the `<head>` aren't part of the dom tree, and so can't be traversed.

Comment: But this does `$head = '<head><title>FooBar</title></head>'
"$($head).filter('title')"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `$('<head><title>FooBar</title></head>')` isn't doing what you think it's doing.

[The jQuery docs explain](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2) what happens when you ask jQuery to create some HTML objects this way:

> If the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, as it is in the above example, the actual creation of the elements is handled by the browser's innerHTML mechanism. In most cases, jQuery creates a new `<div>` element and sets the innerHTML property of the element to the HTML snippet that was passed in. When the parameter has a single tag (with optional closing tag or quick-closing) — `$( "<img />" )` or `$( "<img>" )`, `$( "<a></a>" )` or `$( "<a>" )` — jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript createElement() function.
>
> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, jQuery uses the browser"s .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, **some browsers filter out certain elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed.**

Emphasis added.

Try running `$('<head><title>FooBar</title></head>')` in your JavaScript console, and you'll see it only returns a `<title>` element. The `<head>` was stripped out by your browser. My results in Firebug are:

[image: Screenshot of the results in Firebug]

Filter() searches the set of elements for those matching the selector. You have a set consisting of one `<title>` element, so it returns that element. Find(), meanwhile, looks inside your `<title>` element for a child `<title>` element and finds none to return at all!

Comment: Then how come Liza's example works? After parsing, it's a two element list with one of them being exactly the `<title>` element, so it should generate a same result as mine. Why not?

Comment: @trVoldemort The HTML Liza is checking against safely exists on a webpage the browser engine is fine with. The HTML _you_ are checking against is HTML you're creating on the spot, and the browser engine is stripping certain elements out. Try creating Liza's HTML on the spot with jQuery: `$('<html><head><title>Test</title><script src="../jquery.min.js" ></script></head><body></body></html>')` - you'll get only a title element and a script element, because the rest _were not created_.

Answer (score 0):

Because `find` searches the descendants of its argument. Given a full DOM, it will find `title` just fine:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script
        src="../jquery.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

```
$('head').find('title')
[
<title>​Test​</title>​
]
```